# Does the Exp. Share also spread EVs to other members of the team?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I have been EV training my Pokémon for hours to make them really strong, and then I hear how the Exp. Share can spread the EVs to the whole team.

Now, some threads I go to say that the Exp. share doesn't spread the EVs around, but the other threads I go to say that the Exp. Share **does** put out the EVs to the entire team.

Please, which one is correct?

Answer (score 2):

With the exp share enabled, EVs are given to all pokemon in the party.

Source: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Experience-affecting_item#Exp._Share